# Ionic 4 Cordova Contact Plugin is not working in PWA

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

> Ionic 4 Cordova Contact Plugin is not working in PWA

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
npm install @ionic-native/contacts

public contacts: Contacts

const contactsList = this.contacts.find(['*']);
        if (contactsList !== undefined) {
          contactsList.then(function(value) {

              self.everybody = value;
              // do print
              self.everybodyDuplicate = self.everybody;
              self.everybody = self.everybody.sort(function (a, b) {
                  var x =a.name.givenName;
                  var y =b.name.givenName;
                  if (x < y) return -1;
                  else if (x > y) return 1;
                  return 0;
              });
          });
        }
```

With Some Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: navigator.contacts.find is not a function

Comment: What Browser are you testing on?

Comment: Testing on Google chrome

Comment: In ionic Pwa Contact plugin not working

Comment: and on which OS?

Comment: On Windows OS .

Comment: Windows 10? As i think only this is supported: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#supported-platforms-1